# User register page using (contrib.auth.models User) but facing Not Null Constraint Error

Tags: django, authentication, error-handling, model, notnull

I am first to Django.
I am making a registeration form only to facing NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_userprofile.user_id.
i have been trying to figure out but i can not. Thank you for any help:)

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

This is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post,Comment,UserProfile
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['username','email','password']
```

And this is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse_lazy,reverse
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,DetailView)
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView
from .models import Post,Comment,UserProfile
from .forms import PostForm,CommentForm,UserProfileForm

def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:user_login'))
        else:
            print('unvalid imformation')
    else:
        user_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,'register/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form, 'registered':registered})
```

And this comment shows up

```
IntegrityError at /signup/
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_userprofile.user_id
```

Comment: Where are you creating `user` to be linked with `UserProfile`?

Comment: Your `UserProfile` model (which seems totally useless ATM but I assume you have more fields in it ?) has a non-nullable foreign key on `User`. Your `UserProfileForm` tries to create a `UserProfile` instance (NOT a `User` instance), but since you don't pass it any `User` instance, the database rightfully rejects your `insert` query because it would violate the "not null" contraint on `user_profile.user_id`.

Answer (score -1):

If you get an existing user from your database you can use

```
user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=a)
```

Or you can try this code

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        # If you get an existing user from your database you can use  
        #user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=a)
        user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:user_login'))
```